# How to select group by 2 columns + id?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a problem with data selection using SQL in PostgreSQL database.

I have the following data in one table:

```
ID    ID_X    ID_Y
100   1       2
101   1       1
102   1       1
103   1       2
104   5       10
105   5       11
106   5       10
107   5       11
108   8       20
109   8       30
110   8       20
```

How to write select statement to get the following results?

```
ID    ID_X    ID_Y
100   1       2
101   1       1
104   5       10
105   5       11
108   8       20
109   8       30
```

I know that it is a kind of group by ID_X and ID_Y but how to select also "ID" column without grouping by it?

Maybe there is a way to select using distinct? or group by with subselect? Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function like MIN() or MAX().  In your case you want MIN() to get those specific results.

```
SELECT MIN(ID), ID_X, ID_Y
FROM [tablename]
GROUP BY ID_X, ID_Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `Distinct on`

```
 select * 
    from 
        (
        select distinct on (id_x, id_y) ID, id_x, id_y
        FROM t order by  id_x, id_y,id
        ) q 
        order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want a `GROUP BY`. Use `MIN()` to return each group's lowest ID:

```
select min(ID), ID_X, ID_Y
from tablename
group by ID_X, ID_Y
```

Alternatively, you can do a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.ID_X = t1.ID_X
                    and t2.ID_Y = t1.ID_Y
                    and t2.ID < t1.ID)
```

I.e. return a row as long as there are no (other) row with same ID_X and ID_Y but a lower ID.